# Issue when having multiple getSaveFileName windows at once - closing one window closes the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I have the following function (reduced) in the GUI class. My app is multithreaded so sometimes this function gets called multiple times before the previous once has finished. This shouldn't be a problem but it is.

So when this function is called simultaneously, multiple windows open as expected. For one of the windows I choose a location and click save, it works fine for that window, returning the file location picked. But when I do this the other windows close, returning a null string, despite me not having interacted with them.

Can anyone shed some light on why?

The function is being called via a pyqt signal if that's relevant.

```
def save_file_dialog(self, file_name):
    save_file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save As", file_name)[0]
```

EDIT:
Minimal reproducible example:

```
import threading
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    save_file = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.save_file.connect(self.save_file_dialog)

    def save_file_dialog(self, file_name):
        save_file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save As", file_name)[0]
        print(save_file_name)

def different_thread():
    x = 0
    while x != 3:
        window.save_file.emit("filename")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        x += 1

APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

threading.Thread(target=different_thread).start()
sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

Something interesting to note. Without the time.sleep it works as expected.
Unfortunately my setup means there will always be a delay, however long, between every signal emission.

EDIT 2:
I was able to partially resolve the issue.

Instead of:

`save_file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save As", file_name)[0]`

I did this:

`save_file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)[0]`

For some reason unknown to me, getting rid of those arguments gives the expected behaviour.

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added it